# What settings help to reduce CPU load?

Tags: pc, fallout-3

I made a topic [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95265/fallout-3-runs-better-on-medium-settings-than-low) about why my Fallout 3 runs better on Medium settings than low.
So it seems that my CPU is a bit of a bottleneck.

Which settings are mainly CPU dependent so I can adjust them?

[image]

Comment: This may be edging into loo localized territory.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's wrong with the question? Please explain don't just leave a snide remark and a down vote!

Comment: It wasn't snide, actually.  This question seems unlikely to help any future users, and that's a requirement for questions.  If you remove your specs, it might be more useful.

Comment: @magnetica By 'too localized' he means that it's unlikely many other people will have your exact specifications, and so this question won't be useful to very many people.  However, I don't have a problem with 'small userbase' localization in questions, and I, personally, think it's fine.  But unfortunately, you can't control when or why people downvote.  I *will* mention it in chat though, because there was a discussion just the other day about localized questions and their on-topic-ness.

Comment: I don't particularly think this question is too localized. I just think that not many users care to mess around with the settings.

Comment: I don't see this as too localized. His particularly computer setup has no particularly bearing on which settings are "cpu-dependent".

Comment: Even if it is unlikely that anyone else has these exact specifications, so what?  Who cares if only one person gets something out of a post here, I think that's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Loo localized? Are there bathroom settings in here as well somehow? What a strange game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite black and white because several settings rely on both your GPU and CPU, but reducing your Resolution, Shadows, and Draw Distance (in your case, the settings on the view distance tab) will net you the most performance if your CPU is the weak link.

If you're using an LCD monitor, as most are these days, then you're pretty much stuck with what your native resolution is for your monitor. Technically, you can run it at a lower res and disable any GPU or Monitor scaling, but most people don't/won't do this.

The two most GPU intensive settings are Shadows and Anti-Aliasing.

Comment: Thanks seemed to smooth the fps out a quite a bit more. :D